# Access variable from inner onClick method in outer class in Wicket

Tags: java, wicket

I have a class which looks like this

```java
    private static class LinkTest extends WebMarkupContainer {
        public LinkTest(String id) {
            super(id);
            AjaxLink<Object> link = new AjaxLink<>("link") {
                @Override
                public void onClick(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
                    String content = //... some function call
                }
            };
            add(link);
            // .. how to access "content" variable here
            link.add(new Label("label", Model.of(content)));
            add(new AttributeAppender("onclick",
              new Model(format("alert('%s');", contentModel)), ";"));
        }
    }
```

I'd like to get access of "content" variable inside of LinkTest constructor. Any ideas how to do it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
private static class LinkTest extends WebMarkupContainer {
  public LinkTest(String id) {
    super(id);

    // 1
    IModel<String> contentModel = Model.of("initial value");
    AjaxLink<String> link = new AjaxLink<>("link", contentModel) {
        @Override
        public void onClick(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
            // 2
            contentModel.setObject("a new value");

            // 3
            target.add(this.get("label"));

            // 5
            target.appendJavaScript("alert('"+contentModel.getObject()+"');");
        }
    };
    add(link);
    Label label = new Label("label", contentModel);
    link.add(label);
    //4
    label.setOutputMarkupId(true);
}
```

}

1. The idea is to use a shareable container for the `content`. In Wicket this is the model (`IModel`).
2. When the link is clicked then you update the model
3. To update the Label you need to add it to the AjaxRequestTarget.
4. Don't forget to make the Label Ajax updateable by calling `.setOutputMarkupId(true)` on it
5. By using `target.appendJavaScript(CharSequence)` you can send the newly calculated `content` to the browser

Comment: thanks but I need also make JS call and contentModel is always as initial value and not the new value which I assigned in onClick event ```add(new AttributeAppender("onclick", new Model(format("alert('%s');", contentModel)), ";"));```

Comment: I've added // 5 to my answer. By using AttributeAppender you set the attribute value to the initial value of the `contentModel`. You need to use `target.appendJavaScript(...)` to send the updated value *after* the click of the link.

Comment: its weird if I set as a parameter in alert ```contentModel.getObject()``` nothing happens but if I use ```alert('Test')``` as example then I see popped up message when I click. any ideas why javascript not working with contentModel ?

Comment: I guess there is a JavaScript error because of unescaped (single|double) quote in the produced String. Check your browser's Dev Tools console.

Comment: ok, is it because of characters like "\0\n", right ? I see error in the dev tools console ```VM72:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
    at Object.addElement (core-v-3837323131636430.js:formatted:5174).... ```

Comment: thank you very much for pointing on unescaped characters! It was really that problem! It works now fine! You're the best! @martin-g

Answer (score 1):

Simple to solve by sharing a model between both components.

```
private static class LinkTest extends WebMarkupContainer {
    public LinkTest(String id) {
        super(id);
        IModel<String> contentModel = ()-> /* some function call */;
        AjaxLink<String> link = new AjaxLink<>("link", contentModel) {
            @Override
            public void onClick(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
                target.add(this);
                target.appendJavaScript("alert('"+getModelObject()+"');");
            }
        };
        add(link);
        // .. how to access "content" variable here
        link.add(new Label("label", contentModel));
    }
}
```

Comment: it doesn't really work, the model has not the newest value. I add one line of code in my post where I call javascript behaviour and there contentModel is empty

Comment: Maybe the model is beeing updated, but you can't see the value because `label` is never updated? For ajax calls you always have to specify a component that has `setOutputMarkupId(true)`. In this case you could just write `target.add(this)` after `setModelObject(content)`.

Comment: right label is never updated, so outside of AjaxLink class the contentModel always empty . I need that everytime when I click on link the label should be re-rendered and get the actual value of contentModel. SHould I use may be ```LoadableDetachableModel``` ?

Comment: I updated the example using java 8s lambdas for the function call. Whether you want to use a Loadable detachable model or not depends on what data you are getting and how expensive the call is.

Comment: may be you meant ```target.add(this)``` ? and now the page everytime reloads after click event, and no alert message popping up

Comment: Yes you are right I meant `this`. I can not think of any reason why the entire page reloads.

Answer (score -1):

an anonymous class can access to the members of its enclosing class. So you might do something like this

```
private static class LinkTest extends WebMarkupContainer {
     //Here!
     String content;
     
     public LinkTest(String id) {
        super(id);
        AjaxLink<Object> link = new AjaxLink<>("link") {
            @Override
            public void onClick(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
                content = //... some function call
            }
        };
        add(link);
        // .. how to access "content" variable here
        link.add(new Label("label", Model.of(content)));
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think hat will work. The label will always display null.